# Given a list of dates, how can I combine/format them as a string like "Day1-Day3, Day5 Month Year"

Tags: python, list, datetime, format

**Background:**

I am working on a project that gives me properly formatted JSON `data`. For the purposes of this question, the `data` is not important. Specifically what is relevant to this question is the following **example** list of strings (dates, in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`):

```
dates = [ "2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-23" ]
```

**What I want to do:**

Given the example list `dates` above, I want to combine dates with the same month and year into a single line/string, with a format like so:

```
17-19, 23 APR 2021
```

**What I tried:**

I created a simple iteration on the `dates` list to create a dictionary, broken down like so: `{year: {month: {days}}}`. <s>However this still leaves me with the issue of combining sequential days, e.g. `[17, 18, 19, 23]` needs to become `17-19, 23` when finally printing or creating the string.</s> (See my comment below the code snippet)

It's beginning to feel like a sledgehammer solution for a nail problem. I feel like there has to be a better way to do this with list comprehension or something simpler.

Code snippet:

```
import datetime
dates = [ "2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-23" ]
parsed_dates = {}

for d in dates:
    current_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')

    # local variables just for legibility
    year = current_date.year
    month = current_date.month
    day = current_date.day
    
    # if the current year is not in the dict, add it
    if year not in parsed_dates:
        parsed_dates[year] = {}
    
    # if the current month is not in the year dict, add it
    if month not in parsed_dates[year]:
        parsed_dates[year][month] = set()

    # for the day, simply add to the set (ignore duplicates)
    parsed_dates[year][month].add(day)

# dictionary sorting omitted for legibility
# ...

print(parsed_dates)
```

<s>I haven't continued trying to parse the dictionary into my desired format because as mentioned I feel like I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole here.</s>

*See my posted answer below for the solution, it is definitely not optimal. Hoping someone else has better ideas.*

Output:

```
{2021: {4: {17, 18, 19, 23}}}
```

**Some parameters for the potential solution:**

- I am not in control of the source `data`, this is provided to me
- The date formats will always be a string, with format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Assume all dates are valid, and will successfully parse with `datetime.datetime.strptime` using the format string `'%Y-%m-%d'` (e.g. there are no whacky strings like `2021-50-98`)
- The dates are not guaranteed to be sequential days or months, or in order (e.g. I could have `[ ... "2021-02-05", "2020-01-01", ...]`
- The `dates` list may contain duplicates (e.g. `[ ... "2021-04-21", "2021-04-21", ... ]`)
- No consideration needs to be given to localization (e.g. assume everything is in English, and everyone understands both styles of date format, `DD MMM YYYY` and `YYYY-MM-DD`)
- The solution does not need to be "bullet-proof" (e.g. we can make assumptions on format and input, and that it will always look like the example above; the only variable is the number of dates per list)
- The solution does not need to be extensible (e.g. I only need this as a solution to the above problem given the list of dates with no consideration for permutations or changes to `data`)

Please let me know if any other clarification or details are needed, or if the post is too long. I tried to give as much information as possible but I realize this might be overwhelming to quickly read and formulate potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this question, my current solution is as posted below. It is a ton of code to do something simple, so I'm sure there is a better solution out there. I am happy to accept someone else's answer if they can optimize this or point out a core concept I might be missing.

**Note:** I added `"2021-03-18"` to the `dates` list here to demonstrate breaking up the strings properly after formatting.

Code:

```
import datetime
import calendar

dates = [ "2021-04-17", "2021-04-18", "2021-03-18", "2021-04-19", "2021-04-23" ]
dates_parsed = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') for d in dates]
dates_dict = {}

for d in dates_parsed:
    # local variables just for legibility
    year = d.year
    month = d.month
    day = d.day
    
    # if the current year is not in the dict, add it
    if year not in dates_dict:
        dates_dict[year] = {}
    
    # if the current month is not in the year dict, add it
    if month not in dates_dict[year]:
        dates_dict[year][month] = set()

    # for the day, simply add to the set (ignore duplicates)
    dates_dict[year][month].add(day)

# begin looking through the dictionary for ranges to format
for year in dates_dict:
    for month in dates_dict[year]:
        days = list(dates_dict[year][month])

        day_ranges = [] # a list of lists, used to step through and format as needed
        curr_range = [] # the current list being operated on below

        for day in days:
            # check if current range is empty
            if not curr_range:
                curr_range = [day]
                continue
            
            # if the current range has elements, check if this day is the next one
            # if so, add it to the current range
            if curr_range[-1] + 1 == day:
                curr_range.append(day)
            
            # otherwise, we're not in a sequential day range
            # push this list to the day_ranges list, and clear the curr_range list
            # after clearning, add the current day to the new curr_range list
            else:
                day_ranges.append(curr_range.copy())
                curr_range.clear()
                curr_range = [day]

        # if the curr_range isn't empty when exiting the loop, add it to the day_ranges list
        if len(curr_range) > 0:
            day_ranges.append(curr_range.copy())

        # begin formatting the day ranges
        # this formats something like [[17, 18, 19], [23]] to '17-19, 23'
        day_strings = []
        for d in day_ranges:
            if len(d) > 1:
                day_strings.append(f'{d[0]}-{d[-1]}')
            else:
                day_strings.append(str(d[0]))
        
        # finally, join up each day ranges into one string
        day_str = ', '.join([x for x in day_strings])
        month_name = calendar.month_name[month]
        print(f"{day_str} {month_name[:3].upper()} {year}")
```

Output:

```
17-19, 23 APR 2021
18 MAR 2021
```

(I'm not particularly concerned with the sorting of the year/month for this particular answer, that's easy enough to do elsewhere.)